# curl post testing oauth 2.0 not working while the http example does

Tags: post, curl, oauth, get, oauth-2.0

I am trying to understand how Google authentication works with OAuth 2.0. They give some examples at [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html).

I am having trouble with one of the first steps. I can execute this http request in a browser:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds&client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/back&response_type=token
```

and that works fine.

When I try to convert it to a curl GET operation,

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds&client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/back&response_type=token
```

I get a response that tells me there is an `OAuth 2.0 error: invalid_request`.

Converting it to a POST, I can't get this  operation to work.

```
curl http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth  -d “scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds&client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/back&response_type=token”
```

The response is that the document has moved.

If I try this, I get similar results.

```
curl http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth  -data-urlencode “scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds&client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/back&response_type=token”
```

I have never used curl or OAuth in my code before, so I want to understand some of these basics. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my GET and POST ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a sure answer for you, but I was working on something similar for Instagram and one thing that stumped me for a while was that my redirect URL looked to be the same as Instagram expected, but I kept getting errors.

Like you, when I 'hand coded' the redirect URL, I got the result I expected, but my automated calls to the authentication URL failed. It turned out my ampersands were a url encoded which Instagram compared to the redirect URL and saw they were not identical. I'm not sure if that will get you closer to an answer, but I thought I'd share my experience since your question reminds me of the situation I was in. Good luck.

Comment: John, I just had a chance to refresh my memory on this. You suggestions looks good. I'll let you know how it works, but it may be a few days before I get to look at it.